# Laravel Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: laravel

After creating a fresh Laraver project using:

> laravel new [project_name]

At first it ran, but after running it for the second time I got an error saying:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'D:[path]\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was that the initial directory included server.php file and the second time around it was missing.

For me this was a weird interaction with Avast as it perceived the file as malicious. Check Avast's Virus chest to recover the file to avoid further issues.

*Maybe this will save time for somebody.*

Comment: Yup it seems Avast has a problem with this particular file recently for some unknown reason, I will be contacting them to maybe have a solution for it in the next patch.

Comment: @MrTindervox, you are life saver, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: My lord. This would've taken ages to detect if not for the sound citizens of Stack Overflow. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yet another who can confirm this. Thank you, kind sir. This could have taken hours or days to find. As it was my first sortie with Laravel, I was almost ready to give up on the framework. Now to get learning

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when the `server.php` file is needed in the root directory of the project, if you need it you can create the file and basically this is the code that must contain.

**server.php**

```
<?php
$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. I tried windows 10 - php 8.0- laravel 8 and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you have deleted the `server.php` file from the root of the Laravel project. You can re-create new server.php and put the PHP script as given,

```php
<?php
    $uri = urldecode(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
    if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
        return false;
    }
    require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

or you can go to the official laravel github [repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) to grab the original [server.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/server.php) file.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are probably using Avast antivirus, The solution is simply open the Antivirus-check virus and threats, make server.php an exception and try open the localhost again, it should now work

Answer (score 0):

I'm on **windows 10** also and I had the same issue and error message:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Unknown:
>   Failed opening required 'D:\yourProject\server.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

How to solve this.
On **Avast** antivirus:

- Add route exception to your project path
- Check if the server.php file exists on your root path project, if not it means that antivirus removed it, go to the Avast trunk and restore it.

Stop server and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this(server.php) file into your laravel project

```
<?php

$publicPath = getcwd();

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists($publicPath.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once $publicPath.'/index.php';
?>
```

in this address(vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources);
and add it to exceptions of antivirus that you use it

Answer (score 0):

The Avast antivirus removed the file, open avast app

- Go to protection
- Restore the file (Don't press delete)

Comment: This answer is sort of a duplicate of the accepted answer. It would have been better as a comment or edit on the accepted answer to specify where to look on avast interface.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the server.php file

vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources\server.php

If you are facing the error that means the file is not avaliable, so you have to create it by yourself and paste the code:

```
    <?php

$publicPath = getcwd();

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists($publicPath.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once $publicPath.'/index.php';
?>
```