# PHP Fatal error: Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console/../resources/server.php'

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have installed composer and created laravel file using command laravel new blog and when iam using php artisan serve iam getting this error cannot even find solution for this error please hep me out.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52DaP.png)

Comment: run `composer install`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682640/laravel-warning-unknown-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-in-un)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server.php make a Exception and your Anti-Virus like Avast delete it Automatically. Make turn off your Anti-VIrus Software.

> server.php

file is missing so you got this error, Some antivirus considers that the server.php file is a virus, So he simply removes it.
Another Solution is:

You can also manually create server.php file

1.Open the link: https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-basic/blob/master/server.php

2.Copy all code

3.Open Notepad and paste your copy code

4.save Notepad file and set name server.php

5.Copy the server.php file and paste it inside your Laravel project

6.Run your project again in browser Now you will not get an error and the Laravel project will work properly.

Comment: Where i have to paste this server.php file   'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console/../resources/server.php  this location cannot find

Comment: i have pasted server.php in htdocs/laravel/blog still iam facing same error 
Fatal error: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console/../resources/server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

The file "server.php" is missing because the Anti-virus deletes it.

I'm using Laravel 9 and I find this solution.

1. Get a copy of server.php here: https://github.com/jayimillena/laravel9-server-php/blob/master/server.php
2. Copy the code and save it in this directory

If you're using XAMPP

C:\xampp\htdocs<laravel project>\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console/../resources

If you're using WNMP
C:<laravel project>\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console/../resources

3. Then run the code using "php artisan serve" command

Answer (score 0):

To fix the missing file, just regenerate the vendor directory and the problem will be fixed using the command below.

```
$ composer update
```

Reference Link: https://bobcares.com/blog/laravel-vendor-folder-missing/